Why does panda-css only generate CSS for specific component names in ParkUI?
I am using ParkUI and have encountered an issue where the CSS recipes for components like menu, dialog, and tooltip only take effect if the component has exactly these names.
For example, I created a simple tooltip component that only needs to receive a child and text:
import { createStyleContext } from "@/providers/parkui";
import type { Assign } from "@ark-ui/react";
import { Tooltip as ArkTooltip } from "@ark-ui/react/tooltip";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { type TooltipVariantProps, tooltip } from "styled-system/recipes";
import type { JsxStyleProps } from "styled-system/types";

const { withRootProvider, withContext } = createStyleContext(tooltip);

export interface RootProps extends ArkTooltip.RootProps, TooltipVariantProps {}
export const Root = withRootProvider<RootProps>(ArkTooltip.Root);

export const Arrow = withContext<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Assign<JsxStyleProps, ArkTooltip.ArrowProps>
>(ArkTooltip.Arrow, "arrow");

export const ArrowTip = withContext<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Assign<JsxStyleProps, ArkTooltip.ArrowTipProps>
>(ArkTooltip.ArrowTip, "arrowTip");

export const Content = withContext<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Assign<JsxStyleProps, ArkTooltip.ContentProps>
>(ArkTooltip.Content, "content");

export const Positioner = withContext<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Assign<JsxStyleProps, ArkTooltip.PositionerProps>
>(ArkTooltip.Positioner, "positioner");

export const Trigger = withContext<
  HTMLButtonElement,
  Assign<JsxStyleProps, ArkTooltip.TriggerProps>
>(ArkTooltip.Trigger, "trigger");

export {
  TooltipContext as Context,
  type TooltipContextProps as ContextProps,
} from "@ark-ui/react/tooltip";

export const Tooltip = (props: ArkTooltip.RootProps & { text: string }) => (
  <Root {...props} openDelay={500}>
    <Trigger asChild>{props.children as ReactNode}</Trigger>
    <Positioner>
      <Arrow>
        <ArrowTip />
      </Arrow>
      <Content>{props.text}</Content>
    </Positioner>
  </Root>
);


This code works perfectly, but if I rename the component to something other than "Tooltip", panda-css stops generating the CSS for the "tooltip" slotRecipe.
My questions are:

Why does the CSS generation depend on the component's name?
How can I make the CSS recipes work regardless of the component names?

I tried renaming the Tooltip component to something else, like CustomTooltip, expecting the CSS to be generated and applied correctly regardless of the component name. However, what actually happened is that the CSS was not generated for the renamed component.
